# ggbiplot returning a blank red column

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggbiplot, prcomp

I have a microarray of 47,303 probes and 6 time points of treatment of samples.

They are in a large matrix:

```
dim(microarray)

47303 6
```

I've done the following:

```
pca <- prcomp(x = t(microarray), scale. = T, center = T)
```

Using ggplot2 I'm able to visualise the PCA with the following code:

```
pca.data <- data.frame(micro_9a = rownames(pca$x),
                       X = pca$x[,1],
                       Y = pca$x[,2])

colnames(pca.data) <- c("Induction",
                        "X",
                        "Y")

ggplot(data = pca.data,
       aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_text(label = pca.data$Induction) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Induction), size = 50, alpha = 0.4) +
  labs(x = "PC1 (35.66%)",
       y = "PC2 (26.50%)",
       title = "Principle Component Analysis of the TCP4 microarray") +
  theme_few()
```

[image: ggplot2 generated PCA visualisation]

I would like to use ggbiplot to generate a more informative visualisation like so: https://datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pca-analysis-r.

If I use ggbiplot to do this with the following code:

```
ggbiplot(pca, scale = 1, obs.scale = 1, 
         varname.abbrev = T, var.axes = F,
         pc.biplot =TRUE, circle = TRUE,
         ellipse = T)
```

I get the following graph:

[image: base PCA graph]

However, if I change the one setting `var.axes = T` as so:

```
g <- ggbiplot(pca, scale = 1, obs.scale = 1, 
              varname.abbrev = T, var.axes = T,
              pc.biplot =TRUE, circle = TRUE,
              ellipse = T)
```

then I get the following blank plot:

[image: blank red graph]

Can any help me trouble shoot this?

Comment: I think I have figured it out. The reason why it appears as a blank red column is because there are 61,657 arrows pointing to all the directions of the graph. If I subset just the first 500 rows of the dataframe, this becomes evident,